# What is people’s position to dogs?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, single-word-request

I would like to know how dogs (i.e. all animals) would call us, if they could speak. Who are we relative to dogs?

> Wer ist der Besitzer dieses Hundes?
>
> Der Hund folgt seinem Eigentümer nach Hause.

I’ve also found the following results, but I’m not sure which is in use currently.

> Hundehalter, Besitzer, Führer, Eigentümer

Comment: _I would like to know how a dog (i.e. all animals) would call us, if they could speak._ – Do­sen­öff­ner

Comment: Herrchen, Frauchen

Comment: I have a *Frauchen,* too. I’m a dog. I have a collar and a leash. Am I freaking you out? ;)

Comment: @Jan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog

Comment: Muss man die Hunde fragen.

Comment: @userunknown, I've asked but he just said wauw wauw and always wauw :-))

Comment: You could try to ask a human pet: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_roleplay :)

Comment: @loong Katzen haben Dosenöffner. Hunde haben Herrchen, kein Personal.

Answer (score 4):

Male: Herrchen

Female: Frauchen

Quickly said: just the diminutive of "Herr" and "Frau".

Answer (score 2):

It’s rather simple because you can just go by what somebody says when they are talking *directly to a dog* (that is not their’s — or maybe their’s but they want it to go to their spouse or whatnot).

> Na Brauner, du sollst Frauchen doch nicht immer so mit der Leine hinter dir herzerren!
>
> Schau mal, da drüben, dein Herrchen hat Leckerli!
>
> Und wenn jetzt noch das Herrchen käme, um mit dir Gassi zu gehen …

The structure is basically the same compared to talking to a child. And when speaking to children, it is common for strangers to use *die Mama* or *der Papa* rather than *your mother/father.*

Of course, this *heavily* depends on the animal in question. Or, as the old joke goes:

> Hunde haben Herrchen. Katzen haben Personal.